# Deleting first node without head pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, singly-linked-list, pass-by-value, function-definition

I am trying to make linked list code that makes deletion from first node.I created a struct a

```
struct node{
  int data;
  struct node *next;
};
```

Then added some nodes, without using head pointer, here is my main

```
int main(){
struct node *first = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
struct node *second = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
struct node *third = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
struct node *forth = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

first->data = 1; //assing data in first node
first -> next = second; // link first node with second node

second -> data = 2;
second -> next = third;

third -> data = 3;
third -> next = forth;

forth -> data = 4;
forth->next = NULL;

printList(first);

// deletefromBeg(first);

    //printList(first);

}
```

Here my printList code for printing the list

```
void printList(struct node *n){
while (n != NULL){
    printf("%d\n",n->data);
    n = n -> next;
}
}
```

But this deletion code doesn't work. I just want to delete my first node and list starts second.

```
void deletefromBeg(struct node *first){
struct node *temp;
temp = first;
first = first->next;
printf("%d",temp->data);
free(temp);
}
```

Comment: You want `printList(second)` because `first` is no longer part of the list. But anyway I'd write a proper `InsertList` or `AppendList` or whatever function that allows you to add en element to the list properly,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function gets the pointer first by value. It means that the function deals with a copy of the value of the pointer first

```
void deletefromBeg(struct node *first){
struct node *temp;
temp = first;
first = first->next;
printf("%d",temp->data);
free(temp);
}
```

Changing a copy of the value does not influence on the original value stored in the pointer first.

The pointer `first` defined in main and the parameter `first` of the function are two-different objects. Within the function you are changing the parameter `first` that was initialized by a copy of the value of the pointer `first` defined in main.

You have  two approaches.

Either you have to return the new value of the pointer obtained within the function and assign it to the pointer first in main like

```
struct node * deletefromBeg( struct node *first )
{
    if ( first != NULL )
    {
        struct node *temp = first;
        first = first->next;
        free( temp );
    }

    return first;
}
```

And in main you call the function like

```
first = deletefromBeg( first );
```

Or you should pass the pointer first by reference. In C passing an object by reference means passing the object indirectly through a pointer to the object.

```
void deletefromBeg( struct node **first )
{
    if ( *first != NULL )
    {
        struct node *temp = *first;
        *first = ( *first )->next;
        free( temp );
    }
}
```

And in main the function is called like

```
deletefromBeg( &first );
```

Comment: I understood very well. Thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

Now with this delete function you delete first node and list starts second.

```
void delete(struct node *first) {
*first = *first->next;
free(first);
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect, It copies the second node over the first node and then it deletes the first node.Also it needs to check that there is a second node before it does anything.